# Vim linebreak not work

Tags: vim

I set the following settings:

```
set wrap
set linebreak
set breakat=-
```

And I wish the feel looks like:

```
aaa-bbb-ccc-
ddd
```

but actually:

```
aaa-bbb-ccc-d
dd
```

Comment: maybe instead of `set breakat=-` you should use `set breakat+=-`.

Comment: What is your `set tw?` gives

Comment: @dlmeetei It is 0